# ESP8266 smart wallet project

Tags: android, deployment, esp8266wifi

iam trying to make a smart wallet using esp8266. It is connected to my phone over wifi (can use esp as clint or server ) i want to **program esp8266 to make my phone beep when it is left behind** (or connection break) but iam not able to find any thing please can anyone help . also what other features should i add to my smart wallet project beside tracking and rfid protection

tried looking for example code or a library but didn't find any